# Vuetify - Selected v-radio does not set value on v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, radio-button, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a `v-radio` update a `v-model` value automatically but cannot get it working.

I have already achieved this with a check box like this:

```
  <v-checkbox            
    v-model="arr1[index].isDone" 
    :disabled="checkRecordStatus(index)"                  
  ></v-checkbox>
```

With this code the `isDone` value for the specific array element is automatically assigned a value of `true` when the box is checked. That is, I don't need to call a function to set the value on the array element.

I am trying to achieve the same thing with a `v-radio`. Here is what I have:

```
<v-radio
  v-model="arr1[index].isDone"
  @change="radioSelect(index,'true')"
></v-radio>
```

I can get the value from the `radioSelect` function and set it on the model from there, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it without creating and calling a function, as with the checkbox example. I assumed that a selected v-radio would just set a `true` value on whatever was on `v-model`, but I seem to be missing something. I've had a look at the documentation and can't see anything that handles it.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the base Vue docs, it looks like the way to override the default behaviour of a radio passing a string value is to also use `v-bind:value`, so you could do something like this I think (tested with a vanilla Vue2 component)

I am less familiar with Vuetify but if the component can accept v-bind the below should work:

```
<v-radio
  v-model="arr1[index].isDone"
  v-bind:value="true"
></v-radio>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio-1

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work.